# What is the unit of PostgreSQL shared_buffers?

Tags: postgresql

I want to change my pgsql database config and I wonder what units they use there to describe some values. Mostly I want to know about **shared_buffers**. There is no specified unit of this value, just the provided number.

If my **shared_buffers** value is for example **16384**, is it kB? mB? Bytes? What is the unit of this value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `shared_buffers` setting, you can specify the unit, e.g.

```
shared_buffers = 3840MB
```

In official documentation, it says:

> Avoid integers--you need to know the underlying unit to figure out what they mean.

p.s. Recommended value = 25% of available memory

Reference:

- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-resource.html
- http://samiux.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/howto-performance-tuning-for-postgresql-on-ubuntudebian/

Comment: Yes, but what is the unit if is not specified? I wanna know what is the current value.

Comment: not specified in any documentation. I guess it's **KB**

Comment: Thanks, good to know. So the current value is 16 MB. That helps me a lot. ;)

Comment: The unit is 8kB by default. A little baffling, I know :)

Answer (score 17):

`shared_buffers` is counted in disk blocks. The default `block_size` setting is 8kB, and can't be changed without recompiling the server, so that's almost certainly what you're using. This would mean that `shared_buffers=16384` equates to 128MB.

`SELECT * FROM pg_settings` will show you the base units for a setting, among other things. As [@DrColossos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24550037/1104979) pointed out, `SHOW shared_buffers` will give you a qualified amount, and like [@Raptor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24549648/1104979) said, you can (and should!) specify units for any setting which has them.

Answer (score 12):

When you execute

```
SHOW shared_buffers;
```

I get something like

```
 shared_buffers
----------------
 256MB
(1 row)
```

This tells the the current value.